# Terraform 0.12 issue . This object does not have an attribute named "xyz"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

i have a project that i created in terraform 0.12 and its modularized.

its something like:

```
<project_name>
----sg
    --main.tf
    --variables.tf
    --outputs.tf
----ecs
    --main.tf
    --variables.tf
    --outputs.tf
----efs
    --main.tf
    --variables.tf
    --outputs.tf
----alb
    --main.tf
    --variables.tf
    --outputs.tf
```

i will be calling the outputs values in sg[security group] using remote state.

i was able to call the outputs values form sg to ecs and other modules successfully but while doing same in alb i get following error.
"This object does not have an attribute named "alb_sg"".

the outputs.tf file for sg is

```
output "alb_sg" {
value = [module.alb_sg.this_security_group_id]}

...
...
...
```

Security group Output from terraform apply:

```
alb_sg = [
    "sg-somevalue"
]

ecs_sg = [
    "sg-somevalue"
]

efs_sg = [
    "sg-somevalue"
]
```

alb resource code from alb module :

```
resource "aws_lb" this
{
name = somename
subnets = flatten(module.vpc_presets.subnet_ids)
security_groups = [data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.alb_sg]


internal = "true"
loab_balancer_type = "application"
tags = var.tags
}
```

the error after i do terraform apply from inside alb module

```
Error: Unsupported attribute. 

on main.tf line 12, in resource "aws_lb" "this"

12: security_groups = [data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.alb_sg]

data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs is object with 3 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named “alb_sg”
```

Comment: According to the error message, you are attempting to access nonexistent data from your remote state. We cannot assist further without seeing more information about your remote state.

Comment: remote state has the alb_sg attribute

Comment: @MattSchuchard the remote state has following content.

`
{
"version" : 4,
"terraform_version" ...
...
...
"outputs"" {
"alb_sg": {
"value": [
"sg-somevalue"
],
"type": [
"tuple",[
"string"
]
]
},

"efs_sg": {
"value": [
"sg-somevalue"
],
"type": [
"tuple",[
"string"
]
]

},

"ecs_sg": {
"value": [
"sg-somevalue"
],
"type": [
"tuple",[
"string"
]
]

}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with wrong reference to the remote state. i was referring to different remote state and that was not having alb_sg attribute. after going through the code again i realized that it was coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a mistake in your resource declaration:

It should be `"this"` instead of `this`. See below:

```
resource "aws_lb" "this"
{
   name = somename
   subnets = flatten(module.vpc_presets.subnet_ids)
   security_groups = [data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.alb_sg]


   internal = "true"
   loab_balancer_type = "application"
   tags = var.tags
}
```

You can refer to the [terraform documentation for `aws_lb` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb).

Comment: it still is giving problem. i tried with "this" also.

Comment: Ok, if you could please correct your question... Then just to confirm, you have an output named "alb_sg" and your module is also "alb_sg"? Can you also show how the other working folders are setup?

Comment: And as Matt requested - the content of the remote state. There could be something wrong too even if alb_sg is there... Wondering if `data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.alb_sg` should be `data.terraform_remote_state.alb_sg.outputs.alb_sg` instead?

Comment: Hi , i posted part of the remote state content. i tried to call most of the modules using 
similar code "data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state_sg.outputs.alb_sg" and in most of my projects. but its strange that it is breaking for this module.

Comment: You should edit your question and put it there, it's not readable otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mardemootoo, it was a coding error. i was referring to wrong remote state which was not having the alb_sg attribute.

Comment: Great! You should put an answer and mark it so as to resolve this question. Else it will remain pending.